# Not able to read config.properties using Commons Configuration in a maven web project

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, pom.xml, apache-commons-config

I'm trying to read config.properties file placed in src/main/resources folder for my maven web project, using Commons-configuration api. I'm able to use it without any issues for a normal maven project but in web project this somehow doesn't work. Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>edu.uta.cse</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringSecurity</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>CraiglistWebApp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <jcl-over-slf4j.version>1.7.5</jcl-over-slf4j.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.20.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring Core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${jcl-over-slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.1</version>
     <!--  <optional>true</optional> -->
    </dependency>



    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<build>
    <finalName>CraiglistWebApp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Eclipse project -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Always download and attach dependencies source code -->
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                <!-- Avoid type mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0 -->
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Set JDK Compiler Level -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- For Maven Tomcat Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/CraiglistWebApp</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <!-- <filtering>true</filtering> -->
        </resource>
    </resources>

</build>
```

and I'm reading this file using the below code

```
static {

    Configuration config = null;
    try {

        //config = new PropertiesConfiguration("resources/config.properties"); this package is placed in src/main/java and using this it works perfectly fine
        config = new PropertiesConfiguration("src/main/resources/config.properties"); // this doesn't seem to work

    } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    UPLOAD_LOCATION = config.getString("image.upload.location");
    TABLE_NAME = config.getString("table.name");}
```

Have I missed anything in pom.xml. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an instance of the PropertiesConfiguration object, it will search the current classpath for the file you specify.  With a Maven web project, the `src/main/resources` folder should already be included on the classpath, so there is no need to precede your file name with the directory.  In other words, this should work:

```
config = new PropertiesConfiguration("config.properties");
```